# why previous code isn't executing if require's condition is false in solidity?

Tags: solidity, require

// Why previous code require isn't executing it's before require condition so it should execute why it's happening?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Req {
    uint public year = 2022;
    uint public age = 5;
    function changeAge() internal {
        age++;
    }
    function checkingN(uint _x) public {
        year++;
        changeAge();
        require(_x == 5, "You entered wrong number");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a feature of the `require()` function. It stops and reverts the transaction when the condition is not met.

So effectively, the `changeAge()` is executed (and the sender pays gas fees for its execution) - but then it's reverted.